# GitHubでファイルの追加前に戻したい

Tags: git, github

```
* C.txt追加
|
* B.txt追加
|
* A.txt追加
|
```

順番にA,B,Cのテキストファイルを追加した履歴があります。ここで、B.txtの追加前に戻して、A.txtだけが存在するような状況に戻すにはどうすればよいでしょうか？ `revert` だと元に戻すことができません。

```
* A.txtだけが存在するコミット
|
* C.txt追加
|
* B.txt追加
|
* A.txt追加
|
```

このような状態にしたいです。

Comment: 本家 Stack Overflow での類似質問です: ["How to revert multiple git commits?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463340/5989200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`revert` は `<commit>..<commit>` の形式で複数のコミットを指定できます。更に `--no-commit` オプションを付けることで一旦コミットせずに revert してみて、確認してからコミットできます。

例:

```sh
git revert --no-commit HEAD~2..HEAD
git commit
```

#### 参考

- [git-revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) -- Git Documentation
- [Specifying Revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges) -- gitrevisions -- Git Documentation

Answer (score 2):

既にB.txt, C.txtを追加した際のコミットを公開リポジトリ(GitHub)に対してpush済みの場合には`revert`で打ち消した記録を残すべきですが、変更がまだローカルにとどまっている場合には`reset`を使う方法もあります。

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~2
```